# Need to disable install.package() command in R

Tags: r, dockerfile

We are installing R and R packages with dockerfile and after creating image we need to restrict users to install different packages. Is it possible?

Or is there any way to disable internet of container?

Please suggest any leads

Comment: could you overwrite the defintion of install.packages <- function(){NULL}

Comment: We created image with some no of packages and delivered it to user. Now user should not install any other packages. IS there anything we should add in dockerfile while creating image?

Comment: @pluke The user could just use `utils::install.packages`. Blocking ports seems a better approach.

Comment: @Roland can we block ports while creating image itself? or can you suggest the way how could we block ports in dockerfile(command for blocking ports)